# Is there equivalent clause in hibernate to Oracle 12c's "fetch first ..." clause?

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, hibernate

In oracle 12c we can use `fetch first` clause to select first n rows of a table.
Is there equivalent clause in hibernate to Oracle 12c's `fetch first ...` clause?
example of `fetch first`:

```
select *
  from tbl_order t
 order by t.orderDate desc
 fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Note that i don't want to use `rownum` clause.
I want a solution in `HQL` itself not in hibernate methods like `setMaxResults()`.

Comment: sounds to me like a synonym for limit clause. you can achieve that with `query.setMaxResults()`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, the question that you pointed to it as duplicate is for 2009. there  are many versions of hibernate released after that date. note that my question is about  a solution in hql not in hibernate methods.

Comment: @AliSohrabi The marked answer talks specifically about HQL support of limit, and says that it was never planned to be supported (hibernate-2 supported it almost by omission). The question has pretty high "traffic", so once it becomes outdated, usually someone suggests and approves an edit. [Current version of HQL manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html) does not mention limits, though.

Comment: Ok, you are right. Thanks.